# Pandas Dataframe Comparison - specify mismatched columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes as shown below, `df1` and `df2`:

```
df1 =
            emp_name    emp_city    counts  
    emp_id              
    2       two         city2       3   
    4       fourxxx     city4       1   
    5       five        city5       1   

df2 =
            emp_name    emp_city    counts  
    emp_id              
    2       two         city2       1   
    3       three       city3       1   
    4       four        city4       1
```

Note: 'emp_id' acts as index.
I want to find the difference between `df1` and `df2` and write the name of the columns which has mismatched values. The below code snippet will do that.

```
df3 = df2.copy()
df3['mismatch_col'] = df2.ne(df1, axis=1).dot(df2.columns)
```

Results in `df3`:

```
df3 = 
        emp_name    emp_city    counts  mismatch_col
emp_id                  
2       two         city2       1       counts
3       three       city3       1       emp_nameemp_citycounts
4       four        city4       1       emp_name
```

Now the problem I have is with respect to 'mismatch_col'. It is giving me the names of columns where there is a mismatch in `df1` and `df2`. But, the column names are NOT separated. I want to separate the column names by commas. Expected output should look like below:

```
Expected_df3 = 
            emp_name    emp_city    counts  mismatch_col
    emp_id                  
    2       two         city2       1       counts
    3       three       city3       1       emp_name,emp_city,counts
    4       four        city4       1       emp_name
```

Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `df2.columns + ','` to add commas and then `str[:-1]` to remove the last one:

```
df3['mismatch_col'] = df2.ne(df1, axis=1).dot(df2.columns + ',').str[:-1]
```

Result:

```
        emp_name  emp_city  counts              mismatch_col
emp_id              
2            two     city2       1                    counts
3          three     city3       1  emp_name,emp_city,counts
4           four     city4       1                  emp_name
```

Comment: Extending above question. It worked for most of my tables but failing for one particular condition as below: I have 2 dataframes both are of shape 106*20. In both the tables, I have difference in column 19 and 20. I mean all 106 rows are different. These 2 columns which are like sequence generators (like auto increment values or timestamp values). This line of code is not  giving me the difference. df3['mismatch_col'] = df2.ne(df1, axis=1).dot(df2.columns + ',').str[:-1]. It writes 'NaN' in all rows of df3['mismatch_col']. Please help me understand why this is not working?

Comment: @Bhavyashree717: Could you create a new question with the input data/expected output. It's a bit hard to understand the details with a comment. You can link the question here and I will take a look at it.